# Writing multiple, non-numeric sets of data to .txt file using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
#This provides desired format, but only works with one variable at a time 
np.savetxt("test2.txt", list(zip(shared_A_B)), fmt='%.18s',delimiter='\t')  

#Attempted to write for loop but, this only stores the last variable
cut2=(shared_A_B, shared_A_C, shared_A_B_C..)
for i in cut2:
   np.savetxt("ReportName3.txt", list(zip(i)), fmt='%.18s')

#example input set data
shared_A_B= {'Rik',
            'Rik5',
            'Rikb4'}

#example output written .txt file, this is works but only for idividual variables
shared A_B=Rik
           Rik5
           Rikb4
```

I would like to assign the set data contained within each variable to its own column (primary issue), and eventually define each column with the variable name (this is secondary issue). The only approach I can think of, is it to write a for loop, however this overwrites the data of the preceding variable and does not produce additional columns. I have tried making a numpy array but I ran into errors with dimension requirements, and I think there are probably more practical approaches. If anyone can offer advice, alternative approaches, or a solution, it would be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Alternatively: I have data already successfully written to a .txt file

format=Shared A and B {'Got1', 'Arg2', 'Fpgs'..}

Is there an approach to transpose this data?

Comment: Are you trying to write a CSV file? Can you provide some sample data as well as a sample output file? It's not clear what you are asking, even with the sample code you provided.

Comment: A txt file is written one line at a time, not one column.  Therefore you have to write a line with all the column headers first.  The the first value of all variables, then the second and so on.  `np.savetxt` does this for a 2d array, but is easiest to use with a simple numeric 2d array.  With diverse text it might be easier to do your own file write - using standard Python formatting and `file.write`.

Comment: does file.write have a column compatible command?

Comment: I was hoping for .txt file because Microsoft csv files converts gene names to dates, but it might be the best route